# How can I scrape this table using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I need to scrape all the tables from this page: https://venezuela360.org/arcgis/apps/sites/#/infraestructura-geoespacial/datasets/3d0308d198ba422fbdabd2e1859eb577/data?geometry=-84.125%2C-0.931%2C-49.233%2C14.299.

I tried the following, but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://venezuela360.org/arcgis/apps/sites/#/infraestructura-geoespacial/datasets/3d0308d198ba422fbdabd2e1859eb577/data?geometry=-84.125%2C-0.931%2C-49.233%2C14.299&page=1316'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table_data = soup.find('table', class_='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover')

if table_data is None:
    print("No se encontró la tabla")
```

Comment: Use selenium in python, this won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see in the table comes from Ajax request done via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can try this instead:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = 'https://venezuela360.org/server/rest/services/Hosted/Elecciones_2000_2015_vizJS/FeatureServer/0/query'

params = {
    "outFields": "*",
    "returnGeometry": "false",
    "resultOffset": "0",
    "resultRecordCount": "10",
    "f": "json",
    "where": "1=1",
    "inSR": "4326",
    "geometry": '{"spatialReference":{"latestWkid":3857,"wkid":102100},"xmin":-16639143.449115526,"ymin":-103644.95620412636,"xmax":1793798.7959063984,"ymax":1608544.4773833666}',
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryEnvelope",
    "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
}


all_dfs = []
for params['resultOffset'] in range(0, 20, 10):   # <-- increase the number of pages here (0, 10, 20, ...)
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
    all_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([f['attributes'] for f in data['features']]))

df = pd.concat(all_dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df.tail())
```

Prints:

```
    otros2001  ppt2012  ppt2010  ppt2015  otros2006  otros2007  ppt2013  otros2008  otros2009  votos2012  votos2013  votos2010  votos2009  votos2007  votos2008  votos2006   winner2006  otros2000  nulos2001  otros2012  otros2013  otros2015  nulos2006             municipio  nulos2007  nulos2008  nulos2000        gapvalue2015        gapvalue2012  votos2015  nulos2009  codigo_centro  otros2010  registro2009  registro2007  registro2008  registro2001  registro2000  registro2006  ppt2000  ppt2001  abstencion2009  abstencion2008  abstencion2007  abstencion2006  ppt2008  votos2001  ppt2009 codigo_estado    coord_x  ppt2006   coord_y  ppt2007  votos2000   n       parroquia  abstencion2001  abstencion2000  abstencion2015            estado  abstencion2013  unidad2010  unidad2013  unidad2012  unidad2015  abstencion2012  abstencion2010 winnerswing                                            centro_x                                            centro_y                                                                                                                                                                                                             dirección  unidad2000         swingvalue  unidad2001  registro2012  registro2013  registro2010  unidad2006  unidad2008  unidad2007  registro2015  unidad2009  nulos2012  nulos2013  oficialismo2010  oficialismo2013  nulos2015  oficialismo2012  nulos2010  estrato  oficialismo2015  oficialismo2000  objectid1  oficialismo2001 win2006  oficialismo2008  oficialismo2007  oficialismo2009  objectid  oficialismo2006
15         52        0       44        0         11          0        0          0          0       2687       2606       2295       2476       2096       2081       2413       Unidad          0        129         15         13         59         31  MP. BLVNO LIBERTADOR         33          0          0   0.420902806018707   0.253814663193152       2459         71       10122015         75          3657          3584          3748          3690             0          3596        0        0            1181            1667            1488            1183       33       2013        0        010108  -66.93159        0  10.48817        0          0  49  PQ. EL PARAISO            1677               0            1216  Distrito Capital            1030        1377        1689        1653        1659             949            1404      Unidad       INSTITUTO UNIVERSITARIO PEDAGOGICO DE CARACAS       INSTITUTO UNIVERSITARIO PEDAGÓGICO DE CARACAS                                             URBANIZACION EL PARAISO DERECHA AVENIDA PAEZ. IZQUIERDA AVENIDA PAEZ. FRENTE AVENIDA PAEZ FRENTE A LA AVENIDA P+üEZ DEL PARA+ìSO. FRENTE AL COLEGIO DE ABOGADOS. EDIFICIO           0  0.167088142825555        1148          3636          3636          3699        1311        1308        1359          3675        1530         48         10              721              894        117              971         78        1              624                0         16              684    -251              740              704              875        16             1060
16         31        0       15        0          5          0        0          0          0       1196       1154       1012       1056        904        896       1063       Unidad          0         51         17         10         27         11  MP. BLVNO LIBERTADOR         15          0          0   0.443942133815552   0.296822742474916       1106         28       10122016         44          1499          1461          1515          1569             0          1466        0        0             443             619             557             403       10        911        0        010108   -66.9306        0  10.49002        0          0  15  PQ. EL PARAISO             658               0             485  Distrito Capital             398         657         773         761         761             356             511      Unidad             UNIDAD EDUCATIVA NACIONAL EDUARDO CREMA             UNIDAD EDUCATIVA NACIONAL EDUARDO CREMA                                                      URBANIZACION EL PARAISO DERECHA AVENIDA PAEZ. IZQUIERDA AVENIDA PAEZ. FRENTE AVENIDA PAEZ FRENTE A LA AVENIDA P+üEZ DEL PARA+ìSO. FRENTE AL PEDAGOGICO. EDIFICIO           0  0.147119391340636         553          1552          1552          1523         624         608         639          1591         708         12          3              282              368         48              406         14        1              270                0         17              276    -201              278              250              320        17              423
17         35        0       36        0          7          0        0          0          0       2865       2790       2199       2327       1853       1869       2309  Oficialismo          0        109         19          8         78         63  MP. BLVNO LIBERTADOR         38          0          0  0.0441458733205374  -0.346596858638743       2605         89       10122018         76          3243          3120          3275          3482             0          3100        0        0             916            1406            1267             791       36       1841        0        010108   -66.9296        0  10.48689        0          0  39  PQ. EL PARAISO            1641               0             847  Distrito Capital             704         691        1001         904        1252             629            1179      Unidad  UNIDAD EDUCATIVA DISTRITAL  MARIO BRICEÑO IRAGORRY  UNIDAD EDUCATIVA DISTRITAL  MARIO BRICEÑO IRAGORRY                                                                                  BARRIO BRISAS DEL PARAISO DERECHA AVENIDA ARISMENDI. IZQUIERDA CALLE SECTOR A. FRENTE CALLE PRIMERA DETR+üS DEL PEDAGOGICO. EDIFICIO           0   0.39074273195928         455          3494          3494          3378         486         536         692          3452         753         45         12             1332             1769        138             1897         64        5             1137                0         18             1242    1267             1297             1123             1485        18             1753
18         10        0       14        0          1          0        0          0          0        686        678        574        599        471        491        620  Oficialismo          0         52          9          4         19         27  MP. BLVNO LIBERTADOR         12          0          0  0.0759124087591241  -0.211370262390671        685         30       10122019         18           801           805           817           796             0           819        0        0             202             326             334             199        9        470        0        010108  -66.94289        0  10.48505        0          0   5  PQ. EL PARAISO             326               0             140  Distrito Capital             108         222         287         257         323             100             230      Unidad               CENTRO AMBULATORIO ANDRES ELOY BLANCO               CENTRO AMBULATORIO ANDRÉS ELOY BLANCO  BARRIO BRISAS DEL PARAISO SECTOR A IZQUIERDA AVENIDA ARISMENDI. DERECHA CALLE PRINCIPAL. FRENTE CALLE ESCUELA MARIO BRICE#O IRAGORRY FRENTE A LA PRIMERA CALLE DE BRISAS DEL PARA+ìSO. DETR+üS DEL PEDAGOGICO QUINTA           0  0.287282671149795         139           786           786           804         171         192         219           825         245         18          3              301              384         72              402         19        4              271                0         19              269     250              290              240              324        19              421
19         12        0       10        0          4          0        0          0          0       1421       1396       1094       1199       1058        883       1203  Oficialismo          0         59          7          7         33         18  MP. BLVNO LIBERTADOR          9          0          0  -0.100439882697947  -0.494018296973962       1364         42       10122020         53          1678          1627          1700          1747             0          1624        0        0             479             817             569             421        9        939        0        010108   -66.9182        0  10.48890        0          0  32  PQ. EL PARAISO             808               0             457  Distrito Capital             322         282         394         341         538             297             625      Unidad                             CICLO BASICO PABLO VILA                             CICLO BÁSICO PABLO VILA     BARRIO LA CHIVERA COTA 905 FRENTE AVENIDA GUZMAN BLANCO. DERECHA PROLONGACION AVENIDA GUZMAN BLANCO. IZQUIERDA PROLONGACION AVENIDA GUZMAN BLANCO LIMITE CON SANTA ROSALIA CERCANO A LA ESTACION DE SERVICIO CASA           0  0.393578414276015         181          1718          1718          1719         205         201         737          1821         314         30          6              720              989        118             1043         29        6              675                0         20              687     771              673              307              843        20              976
```